# Rerender every child components after parent state changes React

Tags: reactjs

Hello i am currently facing this situation.
here is the simplified version of the code.

```
const Parent = ({prop}) => {
 const [listOfBool, setListOfBool] = useState([true, false])
 const handleCallback = (e, ev) => {
    var cloneListOfBool = [...listOfBool]
    cloneListOfBool[e] = ev
    setListOfBool(cloneListOfBool)
 }
 return (
    <div>
        <p>{prop}</p>
        <div>{listOfBool.map((bool, idx) => <Child key={idx} prop1={idx} activeProp={bool} parentCallback={handleCallback} />)}</div>
    </div>
 )
}
```

this is the child component

```
const Child = ({prop1, activeProp, parentCallback}) => {
const [active, setActive] = useState(activeProp)
const setThis = (e) => {
    if (active === true){
        parentCallback(e, false)
        setActive(false)
    } else {
        parentCallback(e, true)
        setActive(true)
    }
}

return (
    <>
        <p className={`${active === true ? 'selected' : ''}`} onClick={() => setThis(prop1)}>{prop1}</p>
    </>
)
```

}

prop1 is a number, i use that number to acces the array and change its value.

in the parent i set the list of boolean values, i map through them and i create the childrens. Now when the props of the parent changes, i would like to re render every child . Everything works as i want except for this part. Later on i will need to make a request to get the list of bools. Can you tell me waht is wrong, i have tried a couple of different solutions with no succes. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `key` to force a react component to rerender.

So in this case if `prop` is the parent prop that you want to listen to, you can do something similar to:

```js
  <div>
   {listOfBool.map((bool, idx) => (
      <Child
        key={`idx_${prop}`}
        prop1={idx}
        active={bool}
        parentCallback={handleCallback}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
```

May I ask why you want the component to rerender on a prop it does not use? As much as possible, you should just pass that property to the child, as a setup like this implies some sort of side effect that might be hard to spot.

#### Update (see comments)

```js
const Parent = ({prop}) => {
 const [listOfBool, setListOfBool] = useState([true, false])
 const setActiveAtIndex = (idx, active) => {
   setListOfBool((list) => {
     const newList = [...list]
     newList[idx] = active
     return newList
   })
 }
 return (
    <div>
        <p>{prop}</p>
        <div>
          {listOfBool.map((bool, idx) => (
            <Child
              key={idx}
              prop1={idx}
              activeProp={bool}
              setActive={active => setActiveAtIndex(idx, active)}
            />
         ))}
       </div>
    </div>
 )
}

const Child = ({prop1, active, setActive, parentCallback}) => {
  return (
    <>
        <p className={`${active ? 'selected' : ''}`} onClick={() => setActive(!active)}>{prop1}</p>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, in my code there was a parent of the parent, when i changed a value there, it should reset(later make a call to get data from the server with the prop i pass to the parent) all the childrens, all the childrens need to change, but i need to upload them only when i press a button that i am going to add soon, the component uses the prop i pass from the parent to make a call with le listOfBool that i need for every spot. with your suggestion i have change the key of the parent of the parent to change every time i press a button there and now its re-rendering as i wanted. Thank you

Comment: Glad to help - However, as I mentioned in my answer, note that this is not best practice and you should usually only update through props. Otherwise, you're components might be relying on side effects. You should also look at @Radu's answer, which mentions an important problem with your code.

Comment: Maybe because they have te same name? in my code the prop is activeProp and the children state is active, i made an error while simplifying it is that one the problem? i have corrected the answer

Comment: You should pass the setter inside the child component as well. I've updated my answer to give you an idea.

Comment: aaah ok, so in this case, no need to call the parentCallback function as well as setting the state inside the child right? (i have tried and it works thanks again)

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with your code. I think the children are re-rendered, but if you expect the `className` name to change that's not gonna happed.

`prop1` is a number, but you are using a `===` equality when setting `active`. This means that it will always be false.

The second problem is that you're deconstructing props and get a var named `active` and then declare another one with the same name, shadowing the prop one.

You should have only one source of truth and that's the parent in this case. There is no need for a child state.

```
const Child = ({prop1, active, parentCallback}) => {

return (
    <>
        <p className={`${active === true ? 'selected' : ''}`} onClick={() => parentCallback(prop1, !active)}>{prop1}</p>
    </>
)
}
```

And also, `prop1` is a bad name.

Comment: Hey thanks, i am trying to check the value of active for true/false, not the prop1, which is a number the class change works fine, the prop1 in my code is 'slot', i think i am missing the source of truth part, i mean, it is better to pass the value to the parent and rerender the list every time(maybe i am making an unnecessary component)? thanks for the suggestions (btw i fixed it with the first answer)